# Elasticsearch multiple where and orwhere query

Tags: elasticsearch, where-clause

I need to an elasticsearch query but it must contains multiple where and orwhere clauses like this;

SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE ( (width = 400 AND height = 300) OR (width = 800 AND height = 600) ) AND status = 1 AND deleted = 0

Thank you.

Comment: Use bool query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html
Must clause for AND and should clause for OR

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```js
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "status": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "deleted": 0
          }
        }
       ],
       "should": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "width": "400"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "height": "300"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "width": "800"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "height": "600"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```